# Start a new Function with threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQkZJ.png)hello I want to ask is there a way to create a new thread to start the function and send information to it.
something like the info i need to send to join the thread or something like that.

This is What i mean:

```
private Thread T1;
private Thread T2;

public void Start()
{
    string NaMES = "DEMO";
    int AGE = Convert.ToInt32("44");

    T1 = new Thread(Here(NaMES, AGE));
    T1.Start();
}

public object Here(string NAME, int AGE)
{
    MessageBox.Show(NAME + AGE);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try specifying exactly what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: You know that your code doesn't compile?

Comment: Thread has a new ParameterizedThreadStart or something similar where you can pass in an object as argument :)

Comment: i get error every time i try to run it

Comment: What error? What does it say? Post the error message.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread` has an overloaded constructor that allows you to pass a single parameter, so you could create an object that holds all the data required by your thread delegate.

But probably simpler is to just use a [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx) to create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) around your variables automatically:

```
T1 = new Thread(() => Here(NaMES, AGE));
```

Comment: and how to send it to one function

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The lambda becomes your thread function with no parameters (The `() =>` bit). Your `Here()` function is now just something that the lambda calls.

Comment: i just run the code but nothing works ? any other  ideas